# complexed Issue with hiding ListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

I have a search bar with the property `Text` binded to a string property in my `ViewModel`.

I also have `Behaviors` within the search bar so that every time the text is changed a search is done within a list of objects using `NewTextValue` passed to as the query string.

The issue I have is that, I make the `ListView` invisible until a non-empty string is passed to my Search/Filter command (obviously.. :)). I have tried to enforcing hiding the `ListView` for a couple scenarios e.g. if all text is removed from the search bar.

When an item is selected from the now visible list view I used that item to populate the `Text` property of my `SearchBar`, after which I cannot hide it within code. All attempts have failed and the `ListView` remains visible. **Note**: I explicity created a hide button separately and saw it worked so I am wondering if I cannot tie hiding the view with setting the searchbar `Text` property.

#### View

```
<SearchBar Text="{Binding SearchText}">
                    <SearchBar.Behaviors>
                        <prismBehaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged"
                                                               Command="{Binding FilterOccupationsListCommand}"
                                                               EventArgsParameterPath="NewTextValue"/>
                    </SearchBar.Behaviors>
                </SearchBar>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredOccupations}" IsVisible="{Binding FilteredOccupationsVisible}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Occupation, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

**Please Note** : My ViewModel inherits from `BaseViewModel` which inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `SetProperty()` is what notifies the property. This is quite common with MvvmCross, Prism etc.

#### ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand<string> FilterOccupationsListCommand { get; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        FilterOccupationsListCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(FilterOccupationsList);
    }
    private void FilterOccupationsList(string query)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
        {
            FilteredOccupationsVisible = true;
            var searchResult = Occupations.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(query));
            FilteredOccupations = new ObservableCollection<Occupation>(searchResult);
        }
        else
            FilteredOccupationsVisible = false;
    }

    private Occupation _occupation;
    public Occupation Occupation
    {
        get => _occupation;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _occupation, value);
            SearchText = value.Name;
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    private string _searchText;
    public string SearchText 
    { 
        get => _searchText; 
        set { 
              SetProperty(ref _searchText, value); 
              FilteredOccupationsVisible = false;
            } 
    }

    private bool _filteredOccupationsVisible;
    public bool FilteredOccupationsVisible { get => _filteredOccupationsVisible; set => SetProperty(ref _filteredOccupationsVisible, value); }

    public ObservableCollection<Occupation> _filteredOccupations = new ObservableCollection<Occupation>();
    public ObservableCollection<Occupation> FilteredOccupations { get => _filteredOccupations; set { SetProperty(ref _filteredOccupations, value); } }
}
```

Comment: "after which I cannot hide it within code" - where is the code where you are attempting to do this?  I don't see it.

Comment: Hi , have a check with method of `TextChanged` .Maybe when text is null ,method not show null . You can show code of `TextChanged`, I will check it.

Comment: @Jason i cut the code short so the post would not be long but, what I had was `FilteredOccupationsVisible = false` after `SearchText` property was setusing `SetProperty`. That did not work.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I am using PrismEventToCommand, so when the text is changed `FilterOccupationsList()` is called. Sorry I did not make that clear

Comment: @steve Maybe you can have a try with `INotifyPropertyChanged ` in Model , also not sure prism can use this. Have a look at this about [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm).

Comment: Again @JuniorJiang-MSFT, my mistake. My viewmodel inherits from `BaseViewModel` my base vm class which also inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. I'll update the code to reflect that now. `SetProperty()` is where the property is changed using that interface

Comment: @steve Okey ,thanks for updating. Code of method `FilterOccupationsListCommand` need to be shared.When text changed ,will invoke this mentod .Here can know whether should hide listview.

Comment: The `FilterOccupationsListCommand` literally just calls `FilterOccupationsList()`. Thats it. But i will add that there for more clarity. Thanks

Comment: @steve If using Command , have a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#using-command-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

If not using `Behaviors` in `SearchBar` , you can have a try with `TextChanged` method of itself.

```
<SearchBar x:Name="MySearchBar" Text="SearchText" TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged" />
```

In ContentPage , when text cheanged fire here :

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();    

private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("new -- " + e.NewTextValue + "-- old -- " + e.OldTextValue);
    Console.WriteLine("MyEntry --" + MySearchBar.Text);
    //Here can invoke FilterOccupationsList of MyViewModel 
    myViewModel.FilterOccupationsList(MySearchBar.Text);
}
```

Else if using Command to do , you need to add isntance of `ICommand` in `MyViewModel` to invoke `FilterOccupationsList`.

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand FilterOccupationsListCommand { private set; get; }
    ...

    public MyViewModel()
    {
       FilterOccupationsListCommand = new Command<string>((NewTextValue) =>
                {
                    // Pass value to FilterOccupationsList.
                    Console.WriteLine("SearchBar new text --" + NewTextValue);
                    FilterOccupationsList(NewTextValue);
                });    
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it already by playing around with `True` and `False` for `FilteredOccupationsVisible` after a while. `DeletegateCommand` is a PrismMvvm framework class by the way. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: @steve Great , glad solved it ! When have time , you can share it in answer. Then other people will see solution.